# Bluetooth working very unreliably Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, bluetooth

2 days ago my Bluetooth stopped working on my PC, and I tried booting to the Ubuntu installation disk and it also didn't work (it also didn't work on Windows). Today, I turned on my computer to find that Bluetooth suddenly started working again. At the moment, my Bluetooth keeps turning on and off randomly. Could this be a hardware issue or a software issue? I'm thinking it could be hardware because of the fact that it doesn't work in Windows at the same time that it doesn't work in Linux, and how could I diagnose a Bluetooth hardware issue?

**This is not a duplicate:** [Bluetooth randomly cutting out in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023184/bluetooth-randomly-cutting-out-in-ubuntu)

The reason is because my Bluetooth isn't restored when I restart my PC.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib8Bx.png)

**Update:**

I found a loose 2.5v capacitor (I think, it's part number is damaged) with it's mount missing and the connections loose. I tested my computer and it boots without the component. But it means part of my computer isn't getting it's effects, and I'm not sure where it came from (could it reduce lifespan?). The bios did reset (probably because I disconnected the battery), but for now Bluetooth works. Btw sound, gpu, usb, WiFi, and everything that I tested work. I won't answer this question right now, because I'm not completely sure yet that the Bluetooth will work reliably.

**Update 2:**

Nothing is different, Bluetooth is still working unreliably. I turned on my PC today and Bluetooth is off.

**Update 3:**

I tried to replace the WiFi/Bluetooth module, but now the screw is broken and I can't easily remove it. The bluetooth seems to be working now, but the wifi is down and the only way to use it is to use a wifi dongle.

**Command output:**

`sudo service bluetooth status`:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-04-06 16:22:58 AEDT; 4 days ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1246 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1246 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Apr 10 13:23:29 josua-Satellite-L50-C bluetoothd[1246]: audio-avrcp-target: Protocol not supported (93)
Apr 10 13:23:29 josua-Satellite-L50-C bluetoothd[1246]: L2CAP server failed for Message Notification: setsockopt(L2CAP_OPTIONS): Invalid argumment (22)
Apr 10 13:23:29 josua-Satellite-L50-C bluetoothd[1246]: L2CAP server failed for Message Access: setsockopt(L2CAP_OPTIONS): Invalid argument (22)   
Apr 10 13:23:29 josua-Satellite-L50-C bluetoothd[1246]: L2CAP server failed for Phone Book Access: setsockopt(L2CAP_OPTIONS): Invalid argument (22)
Apr 10 13:23:29 josua-Satellite-L50-C bluetoothd[1246]: L2CAP server failed for File Transfer: setsockopt(L2CAP_OPTIONS): Invalid argument (22)    
Apr 10 13:23:29 josua-Satellite-L50-C bluetoothd[1246]: L2CAP server failed for Object Push: setsockopt(L2CAP_OPTIONS): Invalid argument (22)
Apr 10 13:23:31 josua-Satellite-L50-C bluetoothd[1246]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.84 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Apr 10 13:23:31 josua-Satellite-L50-C bluetoothd[1246]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.84 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Apr 10 15:31:00 josua-Satellite-L50-C bluetoothd[1246]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.84 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Apr 10 15:31:00 josua-Satellite-L50-C bluetoothd[1246]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.84 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

`rfkill`:

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE                 SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth Toshiba Bluetooth unblocked unblocked
17 wlan      phy2              unblocked unblocked
```

**note:** at the time of writing these commands, the Bluetooth isn't working, but the wifi is working.

**I executed `sudo service bluetooth restart` and `sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth`, while Bluetooth wasn't working, and executed the same commands as before:**

```
josua@josua-Satellite-L50-C:~$ sudo service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
```

```
josua@josua-Satellite-L50-C:~$ sudo rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE                 SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth Toshiba Bluetooth unblocked unblocked
 1 wlan      phy0              unblocked unblocked
```

I tried executing `sudo service bluetooth start` as well and I got the same result.

Comment: If bluetooth is part of the wifi card, I would remove and reinsert the wifi card to see if bluetooth works normally again

Comment: I opened up my laptop and found a loose 2.5v capacitor (I think)... Not sure where it came from.

Comment: The capacitor came off the motherboard.

Comment: Please edit your question and post  output of the following commands: 1. `sudo service bluetooth status`, and 2. `rfkill`

Comment: Did you notice the `bluetooth status` output? There were errors: 1. `Protocol not supported (93)` and 2. `Invalid argument (22)`.  But at the  same time `Status: "Running"`. These errors have caused your bluetooth to  become unreliable and unstable. So these services viz. Message Notification, Message Access, Phone Book Access, File Transfer, and Object Push are all out of reach.

Comment: Now issue the following commands: 1. `sudo service bluetooth restart` and 2. `sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth`. Please verify  your whether bluetooth is working or not.  Also, please post the output of `sudo service bluetooth status` and `rfkill` commands.

Comment: When you have capacitors falling out of your laptop you are lucky anything works at all.

Comment: You can be surprised how well things can work even if you remove even neccicary cards and components from a computer, if you remove the graphics card, wifi/bluetooth adaptor, LAN card (Ethernet), ur PC will still turn on and boot properly. A capacitor can be used in timing and/or current stabilisation, so for me its not a surprise my laptop can still work without it, even though it has some issues now. If it were a resistor or a voltage regulator, it could cause more issues, since then parts of the PC aren't getting powered.