# Bluetooth connection unstable after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I recently upgraded Xubuntu to Focal 20.04 (kernel 5.4.0-52-generic) and my Bluetooth earbuds, which had worked fine on 18.04, now experience audio skipping and constant disconnecting/reconnecting when something is playing (with no audio playing, the connection seems stable), almost as if I'm standing 50 feet farther away from the computer. I don't think it's a hardware issue though, since they worked fine before the upgrade and still work fine with my phone. None of these had any effect:

- [Adding](https://askubuntu.com/a/1085778/1144892) `UserspaceHID=true` to `/etc/bluetooth/input.conf`
- [Adding](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023184/bluetooth-randomly-cutting-out-in-ubuntu?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1700418_1023184) `options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N` to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf`
- [Adding](https://askubuntu.com/a/593849/1144892) `options snd-hda-intel model=generic` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
- Restarting various services; forgetting and re-pairing the earbuds

Output of `$ hciconfig --all`:

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
        BD Address: D4:25:8B:3F:07:BD  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 96:6
        UP RUNNING 
        RX bytes:111489 acl:406 sco:0 events:10883 errors:0
        TX bytes:8114541 acl:9757 sco:0 commands:787 errors:0
        Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0x0f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
        Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
        Name: 'pequod'
        Class: 0x1c010c
        Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
        Device Class: Computer, Laptop
        HCI Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Revision: 0x1100
        LMP Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Subversion: 0x1100
        Manufacturer: Intel Corp. (2)
```

Output of `dmesg | grep blue`:

```
[187013.475567] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810225019140f00
[187013.475574] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-22.50.19.14.f.bseq
[187013.824513] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[220522.386060] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000863ca52c failed to resubmit (2)
[220530.439597] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810225019140f34
[220530.439603] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel device is already patched. patch num: 34
```

Excerpt from syslog during a disconnect/reconnect:

```
Nov  4 18:31:22 pequod systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Nov  4 18:31:27 pequod geoclue[1909]: Failed to query location: Forbidden
Nov  4 18:31:27 pequod systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill.service: Succeeded.
Nov  4 18:31:31 pequod systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Nov  4 18:31:31 pequod systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Nov  4 18:31:31 pequod kernel: [222078.184078] debugfs: File 'le_min_key_size' in directory 'hci0' already present!
Nov  4 18:31:31 pequod kernel: [222078.184081] debugfs: File 'le_max_key_size' in directory 'hci0' already present!
Nov  4 18:31:31 pequod geoclue[1909]: Failed to query location: Forbidden
Nov  4 18:31:36 pequod systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill.service: Succeeded.
Nov  4 18:31:37 pequod geoclue[1909]: Failed to query location: Forbidden
Nov  4 18:31:38 pequod bluetoothd[3935891]: a2dp-source profile connect failed for 9C:58:9A:00:87:06: Device or resource busy
Nov  4 18:31:38 pequod kernel: [222085.167001] input: Fada-M2_R (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input37
Nov  4 18:31:40 pequod geoclue[1909]: Failed to query location: Forbidden
Nov  4 18:31:41 pequod bluetoothd[3935891]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_9C_58_9A_00_87_06/sep1/fd9: fd(42) ready
Nov  4 18:31:41 pequod rtkit-daemon[1407]: Supervising 7 threads of 7 processes of 1 users.
Nov  4 18:31:41 pequod rtkit-daemon[1407]: Successfully made thread 3952868 of process 1403 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Nov  4 18:31:41 pequod rtkit-daemon[1407]: Supervising 8 threads of 8 processes of 1 users.
Nov  4 18:31:45 pequod geoclue[1909]: Failed to query location: Forbidden
Nov  4 18:32:00 pequod geoclue[1909]: message repeated 3 times: [ Failed to query location: Forbidden]
Nov  4 18:32:01 pequod systemd[1]: blueman-mechanism.service: Succeeded.
Nov  4 18:32:02 pequod geoclue[1909]: Failed to query location: Forbidden
Nov  4 18:32:38 pequod geoclue[1909]: message repeated 7 times: [ Failed to query location: Forbidden]
Nov  4 18:32:43 pequod systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Nov  4 18:32:43 pequod anacron[3953958]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2020-11-04
Nov  4 18:32:43 pequod anacron[3953958]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Nov  4 18:32:43 pequod systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
Nov  4 18:32:44 pequod geoclue[1909]: Failed to query location: Forbidden
Nov  4 18:32:54 pequod geoclue[1909]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed to query location: Forbidden]
Nov  4 18:32:56 pequod acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 19
Nov  4 18:32:58 pequod kernel: [222165.268075] input: Fada-M2_R (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input38
Nov  4 18:32:59 pequod geoclue[1909]: Failed to query location: Forbidden
Nov  4 18:33:02 pequod bluetoothd[3935891]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_9C_58_9A_00_87_06/sep1/fd10: fd(44) ready
```