# Bluetooth headphones cutting out sporadically in 20.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

I am using Apple Airpods and recently installed a new 20.04 version on my laptop. The Airpods connect but the sound at the beginning of usage is a bit choppy. After a few seconds it works smoothly. Then, at some random point in time the sound gets choppy and either recovers or ends up to stop working completely. I then have to restart bluetooth and reconnect the headphones. Rinse and repeat. I tried the solutions here: [Bluetooth randomly cutting out in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023184/bluetooth-randomly-cutting-out-in-ubuntu)
but they did not work.

I am using kernel `5.8.0-41-generic` and I am connected to the internet via an Ethernet cable.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:

**BT Device:**

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 [8086:0010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0316 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0-CRW
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b604 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera (1280x720@30)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0461:4d51 Primax Electronics, Ltd 0Y357C PMX-MMOCZUL (B) [Dell Laser Mouse]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046a:0113 Cherry GmbH CHERRY Wired Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: I cannot comment yet so writing here. Sounds like a driver issue but please provide more information. Either run `sudo btmon`,
or share the related part of `/var/log/syslog`. My biggest guess would be it is due to corrupted [PulseAudio.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio), however it might be also related to the **bluez** as well. Hence, please try the solution available [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037370/ubuntu-18-04-bluetooth-device-disconnects-right-after-connect-on-lenovo-p50)

Comment: What is the BT device? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Hi @Pilot6 just edited my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi at the same time, this could be a reason why this is happening. Try to disable `bt_coex` by running:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"
```

Reboot to test.

The setting can be reverted by:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf
```

Comment: Tested for almost a full day of work and it seems to have solved the problem. Many thanks for the help. It is weird though because my wifi is usually off as I use an ethernet cable. Could simply having bt_coex running have caused the problem and not necessarily connecting to wifi?

Comment: It may be. The bt_coex technology is really poor in iwlwifi. But it is enabled by default.

Comment: Is there another driver that ubuntu users should/could use?

Comment: No, there is no separate BT driver.

Comment: Ok thanks and lastly would keeping it disabled have any side effects? I.e. wifi not working stably or so.

Comment: There shouldn't be any serious effects. Maybe maximum Wi-Fi speed be lower when using the headphones. But it is a guess.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help

Comment: Is this working for anyone ? I have the same problem and besides the bluetooth headset i'm using a mouse and keyboard, these last 2 had the same problema by it seems to have solved by using the bluetooth adapters that comes with the devices plugged in the USB ports. So only the headset is using the notebook bluetooth. The weirdest thing is that I have two users and this happens only to one.