# Choppy and speeding up audio sporadically (in browsers) on bluetooth earbuds

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

I found this issue while playing videos (in any site) in both Brave and Firefox browser.

This issue doesn't occur while playing the same video in VLC.

I tried fixing the 2.4 GHz Wifi interference issue: https://askubuntu.com/a/1314729

But it didn't work.

Thank you for taking your time.

`$ lspci -nn | grep -i network`

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:a370] (rev 10)
```

`$lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5621 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. HD WebCam
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I'm on version: 22.04 LTS.